# Combining Result MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to combine few result into 1 table to be shown in PHP, bad thing is there is no unique key to identify it, Here is my mysql table data:-

```
ServiceGroup    Name      Moperator          ShortCode  
--------------  ---------  -----------------  ---------  
INTEGRAT        norman     KW_DTAC            11111             
KW_I2C          norman     KW_ZAIN            00000            
AB_MK           norman     HUT/TRUEMOVE       4541311           
INTERGRAT       amanda     KW_DTAC            11111
```

In the table listed, the name amanda and norman has the same value, however I want the result to be shown like this on PHP.

```
ServiceGroup    Name              Moperator          ShortCode  
--------------  ---------         -----------  ---------  
INTEGRAT        norman,amanda     KW_DTAC            11111             
KW_I2C          norman            KW_ZAIN            00000            
AB_MK           norman            HUT/TRUEMOVE       4541311
```

How should I put it on PHP and what should the query looks like? This is example my query:-

```
SELECT Distinct userfilters.ServiceGroup, userdetails.Login, userfilters.Moperator, userfilters.ShortCode FROM userdetails INNER JOIN userfilters ON userfilters.UserDetailsID=userdetails.UserDetailsID AND Login IN ('amanda', 'brandon', 'bryan', 'christina', 'johnny', 'larry', 'monica', 'norman', 'eko') ORDER BY ServiceGroup DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the data by the unique columns and use `grop_concat` to put the login in a comma seperated list

```
SELECT f.ServiceGroup, 
       group_concat(d.Login) as logins,
       f.Moperator, 
       f.ShortCode 
FROM userdetails d
INNER JOIN userfilters f ON f.UserDetailsID = d.UserDetailsID 
WHERE d.Login IN ('amanda', 'brandon', 'bryan', 'christina', 'johnny', 'larry', 'monica', 'norman', 'eko') 
GROUP by f.ServiceGroup, f.Moperator, f.ShortCode
ORDER BY f.ServiceGroup DESC
```

Comment: Nice! So how I do echo the result in PHP?

Comment: Come on @Furry, I think that you can google: loop through the result set http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php  or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I found the solution I need to declare it AS SOMETHING in order for the result to come out. Thanks!